# In Doctrine 2 how to set collection which can have own collection?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using zf2 and I have entity DepositDict which can have many periodTimeAmounts. Each of periodTimeAmount can have many periodMoney elements. I can save to DB my entity with many periodTimeAmounts but periodMoney is saved only for the last periodTimeAmount entity.

**DepositDict**

```php
<?php
/*...*/

class DepositDict
{
/*...*/

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DepositDict\Entity\DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount", mappedBy="depositDict", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $periodTimeAmounts;


public function __construct() {
    $this->periodTimeAmounts = new ArrayCollection();
}

/*...*/

public function getPeriodTimeAmounts()
{
    return $this->periodTimeAmounts;
}

public function addPeriodTimeAmounts(Collection $periodTimeAmounts)
{
    if ( $this->getPeriodType() == self::PERIOD_TYPE_TIME_AMOUNT ) {

        foreach ( $periodTimeAmounts as $periodTimeAmount )
        {
            $periodTimeAmount->setDepositDict($this);
            $this->periodTimeAmounts->add($periodTimeAmount);
        }
    }
}

public function removePeriodTimeAmounts(Collection $periodTimeAmounts)
{
    foreach ( $periodTimeAmounts as $periodTimeAmount )
    {
        $periodTimeAmount->setDepositDict(null);
        $this->periodTimeAmounts->removeElement($periodTimeAmount);
    }
}

}
?>
```

**DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount**

```php
<?php
/*...*/

class DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount
{

/*...*/

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DepositDict\Entity\DepositDict", inversedBy="periodTimeAmounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="deposit_dict_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $depositDict;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DepositDict\Entity\DepositDictPeriodMoney", mappedBy="periodTimeAmount", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $periodMoney;


public function __construct() {
    $this->periodMoney = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getDepositDict()
{
    return $this->depositDict;
}

public function setDepositDict(DepositDict $depositDict=null)
{
    if ( $depositDict === null || $depositDict instanceof DepositDict ) {
        $this->depositDict = $depositDict;
    }
    else {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$depositDict must be instance of Entity\DepositDict');
    }
}

public function getPeriodMoney()
{
    return $this->periodMoney;
}

public function addPeriodMoney(Collection $moneyPeriods) //changed name because money is uncountable
{
    foreach ( $moneyPeriods as $moneyPeriod )
    {
        $moneyPeriod->setPeriodTimeAmount($this);
        $this->periodMoney->add($moneyPeriod);
    }
}

public function removePeriodMoney(Collection $moneyPeriods)
{
    foreach ( $moneyPeriods as $moneyPeriod )
    {
        $moneyPeriod->setPeriodTimeAmount(null);
        $this->periodMoney->removeElement($moneyPeriod);
    }
}

/*...*/

}
?>
```

**DepositDictPeriodMoney**

```php
<?php
/*...*/

class DepositDictPeriodMoney
{
/*...*/


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DepositDict\Entity\DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount", inversedBy="periodMoney")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="deposit_dict_period_time_amount_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $periodTimeAmount;

/*...*/

public function getPeriodTimeAmount()
{
    return $this->periodTimeAmount;
}

public function setPeriodTimeAmount(DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount $periodTimeAmount=null)
{
    if ( $periodTimeAmount === null || $periodTimeAmount instanceof DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount ) {
        $this->periodTimeAmount = $periodTimeAmount;
    }
    else {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$periodTimeAmount must be instance of Entity\DepositDictPeriodTimeAmount');
    }
}

}
?>
```

What's missing?

Comment: if ( $depositDict === null || $depositDict instanceof DepositDict ) {
        $this->depositDict = $depositDict;
    }
    else {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$depositDict must be instance of Entity\DepositDict');
    }

Comment: This code is unnecessary because type checking will already be done by php at public function setDepositDict(DepositDict $depositDict=null). Consider creating DepositDictInterface to allow for easier extending!

Answer (score 1):

*Important*

**Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.**

Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored. Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)

- OneToMany associations are never the owning side.
- The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the owning side
- The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
- ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.
- OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.

New entities in collection are not automatically managed by doctrine.

At first please make sure you call persist before you flush.

```
$em->persist($entity); 
$em->flush();
```

You already have **cascade persist** and **remove** options set - that is good.

The next thing you want to try is adding the **merge option** to your cascades.
If your related entities are for some reson detached then they will be merged, example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DepositDict\Entity\DepositDictPeriodMoney", mappedBy="periodTimeAmount",   cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 */
```

merge : Cascades merge operations to the associated entities.

Comment: I've created entities using all rules above, I've also tried to add merge option but it didn't solve my issue